# iContact Search with email in API2.2

Tags: php, icontact

I have faced an issue while integrating the iContact API 2.2
The problem  is i cannot search a contact details with email.
the result is null nothing return .

what i did is :

```
$res = $oiContact->getContactWithEmail("myemail@gmail.com");//not working
echo "<pre/>";
print_r($res);
```

In the API library :

```
public function getContactWithEmail($Email) {
        // Make the call and return the data
        $this->aSearchParameters['status'] = 'total';
        $this->aSearchParameters['email'] = $Email;
        //$this->aSearchParameters['mytermSearchType'] = 'eq';
        return $this->makeCall("/a/{$this->setAccountId()}/c/{$this->setClientFolderId()}/contacts", 'GET', null, 'contact');
    }
```

When i try to search with contact Id I got full details of the contact but email is not working how ?

is that not possible with this icontact API.2.2

But i found something similar in C# .NET [here](http://www.mitchsmind.com/icontact-api-integration-with-c-net)

Any solution is available with php ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found solution for this problem.

Also i found 2 more additional methods for iContact API using php. If any one face the same issue or some one will works on iContact api it will help them, click [here](http://www.walkswithme.net/icontact-api-with-php) to view in details.

Comment: Wow - Thank you for finding this and sharing.